# Replace tags in a string by reading dynamic columns values from a table

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql

Using TSQL, I want to replace tags in a string by reading values from a column in a table.
E.g. I want to call:

```
DECLARE @TaskID nvarchar(10) = 'T001';
DECLARE @MyString nvarchar(100) = 'The person name is <FirstName>';
SELECT @Result = dbo.ReplaceTags(@TaskID, @TextWithTags)
```

It should then return:

> The person name is Peter

Provided that Peter is stored in col FirstName where TaskID = T001.

This is what I have:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReplaceTags
(
    @TaskID nvarchar(10),
    @TextWithTags nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @Tag nvarchar(30)

    DECLARE @TagStart INT;
    DECLARE @TagEnd INT;
    SET @TagStart = CHARINDEX('<', @TextWithTags) + 1;
    SET @TagEnd = CHARINDEX('>', @TextWithTags, @TagStart);
    SET @Tag = SUBSTRING(@TextWithTags, @TagStart, @TagEnd - @TagStart);

    DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(100) = QUOTENAME(@Tag); 
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT @Result = ' + @ColumnName + ' FROM Tasks WHERE TaskID = @TaskID';

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@TaskID NVARCHAR(10), @Result NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @TaskID, @Result OUTPUT;

    SET @TextWithTags = REPLACE(@TextWithTags, '<' + @Tag + '>', @Result)

    RETURN @TextWithTags
END
```

When testing, I get:

> Error is: Msg 557, Level 16, State 2, Line 14 Only functions and some
> extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

I understand the error, but I do not know how to fix.
Any ideas?

Comment: Those aren't "tags" - just because it's text enclosed in angle-brackets... I'd say you're trying to parse/replace _placeholders_, not "tags".

Comment: The error is because you can't use `EXEC sp_executesql ` from within a `FUNCTION`.

Comment: You'll need to use a procedure with an output parameter; use of dynamic sql is prohibited in functions and it's very well documented.

Comment: This isn't a job for T-SQL, "fix" it by using a different language; ideally your presentation layer's.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you unpivot the tasks table. Assuming its not too big performance might be OK. There is certainly a cleaner better performing way to write this but this does work.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReplaceTags
(
    @TaskID nvarchar(10),
    @TextWithTags nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max) 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @TagStart INT;
    DECLARE @TagEnd INT;
    DECLARE @Tag nvarchar(30);
    SET @TagStart = CHARINDEX('<', @TextWithTags) + 1;
    SET @TagEnd = CHARINDEX('>', @TextWithTags, @TagStart);
    SET @Tag = SUBSTRING(@TextWithTags, @TagStart, @TagEnd - @TagStart);

    DECLARE @Result nvarchar(100)
    SELECT TOP 1
        @Result = REPLACE(@TextWithTags, '<' + @Tag + '>', t.PropertyValue)
        FROM 
        (
        SELECT 
            TaskID 
            , u.PropertyName
            , u.PropertyValue
            FROM Tasks  
            UNPIVOT (PropertyValue FOR PropertyName IN ([FirstName], [LastName]) ) as u 
        ) t
        WHERE t.TaskID = @TaskID and t.PropertyName = @Tag

    RETURN @Result
END
```

Comment: Why not use an inline table-valued function?

Comment: as I said "There is certainly a cleaner better performing way to write this". I'm no SQL expert so I tend to think of rudimentary ways of doing things. Perhaps post you solution using a TVF?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. First time I've heard of unpivot. However I still get the same error that "Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function."

Comment: If you use the function exactly as it is in my answer it will work. Here's a dbfiddle showing it working including some sample data https://dbfiddle.uk/OG0CZ4J5